# Query to count two fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to do 2 counts on the data of a table with a grouping on a field.
Here is an example of data :

```
 sends_id | status | result
----------+--------+----------
 119      | er     | 7dccs11x
 119      | er     |
 120      | po     | 5bde48u1
 120      | pu     |
 121      | po     | a1d9tbg8
```

I try to do this :

- Count the number of lines with sends_id identical -> n_total
- Count the number of lines including status = "po" and result = non-empty value

What should give me this:

```
 sends_id | n_total | n_ok
--------------------+------
 119      | 2       | 0
 120      | 2       | 1
 121      | 1       | 1
```

I wrote this :

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT
        sends_id,
        COUNT(sends_id) AS n_total,
        CASE WHEN status = 'po' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS po
    FROM resource
    GROUP BY sends_id, status
)
SELECT sends_id, sum(po) AS n_ok, n_total
FROM a
GROUP BY sends_id, n_total;
```

```
 sends_id | n_total | n_ok
--------------------+------
 119      | 2       | 0
 120      | 1       | 1
 121      | 1       | 1
```

What does not go is that the lines with 121 on 2 different statuses.
I do not see how to take into account this ...

An ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called conditional aggregation.

```
select
  sends_id,
  count(*) as total,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'po') as po
from resource
group by sends_id
order by sends_id;
```